# org-table to calc matrix and back again?

Tags: org-mode, org-table, calc

Is it possible to feed data from an org table into calc as a matrix, and then get it out again as a vector to fill in a column?

For example, if I have:

```
|           | Fund A | Fund B | Fund C | Combined |
| US        |     .1 |     .8 |     .5 |          |
| Europe    |     .2 |     .1 |     .4 |          |
| Pacific   |     .7 |     .1 |     .1 |          |
| Weighting |     .3 |     .5 |     .2 |          |
```

I would like to use a calc formula to matrix-multiply the data from the first three rows of numbers by the (transposed) weighting in the last row of numbers, and insert the result in the final column, like this:

```
|           | Fund A | Fund B | Fund C | Combined |
| US        |     .1 |     .8 |     .5 |      .53 |
| Europe    |     .2 |     .1 |     .4 |      .19 |
| Pacific   |     .7 |     .1 |     .1 |      .28 |
| Weighting |     .3 |     .5 |     .2 |          |
```

I was hoping maybe something like this would achieve that if inserted in the top cell of the last column -- but this is incorrect: no output is produced in the table:

```
=($2@2..$2@4) * trn($4@2..$4..@4)
```

If it's not possible using calc, is it possible using elisp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
|           | Fund A | Fund B | Fund C | Combined |
|-----------+--------+--------+--------+----------|
| US        |     .1 |     .8 |     .5 |     0.53 |
| Europe    |     .2 |     .1 |     .4 |     0.19 |
| Pacific   |     .7 |     .1 |     .1 |     0.28 |
| Weighting |     .3 |     .5 |     .2 |          |
#+TBLFM: @2$>..@>>$> = ($2..$>> * trn(@>$2..@>$>>))_1
```

In words: set the last column of rows 2 through one before the last row equal to the first element of the vector (`_1`) that is the product of that row vector (`$2..$>>` i.e. cols 2 through one before the last column) with the transpose of the row vector in the last row and the same columns (`@>$2..@>$>>`).

The matrix product is a 1x1 matrix but calc interprets it as a vector: I first tried  [extracting the element](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#Extracting-Elements) using both row and column (`_1_1`) but the second `_1` went unused, so I just deleted it.

Comment: Surely the matrix product is 4 x 1, not 1 x 1?  Is three some way to visualise the result of the calc expression before it gets substituted back into the org table?

Comment: It's not done all at once: it's done row by row, so it's the product of a 1x3 row vector (say the US one) and the transpose of another 1x3 row vector (the weights), so the result is indeed 1x1. You can turn on formula debugging (`C-c {`) and watch it step by step.